# iOS - NavigationBar in UIPageViewController overlap the status bar

Tags: uipageviewcontroller

My app is build with iOS8 and deployment target is iOS7.

I have a UIPageViewController as the root controller. The first page is a normal view controller without navigation controller. The Second page is a table view controller which has a navigation controller. when scrolling to the second page, the navigation bar overlaps the status bar. After scrolling is done, the navigation bar will move down a little and become normal.

It's only happen in iPhone6p. Other devices are correct.
Does anyone have the same issue?

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution ?